# Finding the maximum value of an intersection in a Venn Diagram.

Tags: probability

Given that P(A) = $2/5$, P(B $\cap$ C) = $1/5$ and P(A' $\cap$ B' $\cap$ C') =  $1/10$, where A and B are independent events and A and C are mutually exclusive events while A' and C' are not mutually exclusive, what is the maximum value of P(A  $\cap$ B)?

While working on the problem, I was able to come up with the diagram below, but I am unable to figure out why the correct answer in the answer key is  $2/15$. What should I be equating 0.5-0.6b to exactly to get the a value of b?

(I denoted P(B) = b in the diagram)

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to have $b$ as big as possible; from here $0.5-0.6b=0\iff b=5/6$.  Then $0.4b=1/3$.

Comment: Follow-up question, what would I equate it to for a smallest possible value of b?

Comment: In that case you want to have $b$ as small as possible, i.e., $b-1/3$.